# How do I get verbose output from Maven in the Eclipse console?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I am trying to figure out why a maven project is not packaging a jar. This is a builds successfully on my coworkers computers. There are no errors when I build, but the jar is not in the destination folder. I was hoping that by getting more verbose output from the maven process, that I could determine the differences between what is happening on my installation, and on other peoples installations.

Answer (score 69):

Choose "Run As" -> "Maven build.." or open your Run/Debug configuration

There you can enable `Debug output` or append a `-X` behind your goals.