# Maven project Creation - While creating project from Eclipse failed

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, jbpm

I am able to create the maven project from command line but not able to create project from eclipse.I have configured same maven as external in eclipse. When i am trying to create maven project , its giving me below error. How to fix the below error.

My eclipse version is kepler

```
 Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven- resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to   read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-  
  plugin:jar:2.5
 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

Please advise.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, say at work? You could try deleting everything in `.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5` or wherever your Maven repository lives.

Comment: After deleting the jar files from .m2 location , again getting the same error.

Comment: Just the jar files?  I would try deleting everything.

Comment: I deleted .m2 itself. When i am creating the project again creating .m2 with all the files.But getting same error.

Comment: Try running Maven with `Debug output` turned on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898801/how-do-i-get-verbose-output-from-maven-in-the-eclipse-console

Comment: While creating project itself getting this error. Id i have project then i will as debug output mode.

Comment: @user2848031: can i please ask you to vote the answer if it helped, even if a bit in late XD! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1: Delete .M2 Content
2: Set the Proxy configuration in settings.xml

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>proxy.com</host>
  <port>xxxx</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```

Be careful! don't put any username and passowrd if proxy is without auth

3: Close Eclipse..and reopen

4: clean and update project configuration

5: verify the java buld path used for the project configuration

**6: Try use the Maven embedded in eclipse** just for a test, to see if the problem is the external Maven installation corrupted