# Maven 3.8.0 Compiler - Fatal error compiling: release version 11 not supported

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu, java-11

I'm unable to build using Java 11 with the latest version of the maven-compiler-plugin.

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
<build>
```

when I try to build using Maven:

```
➜  mvn clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 80 source files to /home/mip/service/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.859 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-01T11:20:55+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/124M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project service: Fatal error compiling: release version 11 not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here are the Maven and Java versions which I am using:

```
➜  mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.2
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 10.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family:     "unix"
➜  /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version
openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

Could Java 11 identifying itself as "10.0.1" be causing the problem? If I modify my pom.xml to `<release>10</release>` then it builds with no issue, even though I do not have Java 10 installed.

```
➜  ~ /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac -version
javac 10.0.1 

➜ javac --release 11 SomeClass.java
javac: release version 11 not 
supported Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

I think this is an issue with the Ubuntu `openjdk-11-jdk` package:

```
➜  ~ sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-11-jdk is already the newest version (10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
```

Comment: @mip - strangely, the paths look like Java 11, but if you notice the version used by maven is Java10. I am pretty sure, your configurations are not proper. Also, how about updating your maven version to `3.5.4`?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/a/1037655

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts/+bug/1796027

Comment: Also, make sure you're using a JDK (with javac) and not the JRE from the openJDK project (which is called _java-11-openjdk-11.0.1.13-3.el7_6.x86_64_ on RedHat, for instance).

Comment: This is most likely because Ubuntu at that time was prepared for Java 11 but only Java 10 was available. This was most likely because there was a lot of uproar about Java 8 not being back ported earlier.

Answer (score 60):

mvn need `JAVA_HOME` to be set. I faced the same issue and setting up `JAVA_HOME` to correct JDK did the trick.

Comment: For people on Linux, use `export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java>`. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/13752604/2966288

Comment: For completeness sake, for people on Windows, use `$env:JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java>` in powershell, or `set JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java>` in cmd.

Comment: Adding to what AvahW has mentioned, you can also refer to this post https://askubuntu.com/a/175547 on where to set the java version

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this error while building a java project in a docker container.  It must've had something to do with the way maven was installed, because it went away when I based my container on the [official maven image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven).

Particularly, this meant using the following in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim
```

---

Upon further investigation, the crucial difference is that I had the package `java-11-openjdk`, but I needed `java-11-openjdk-devel`.

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar issue in centOS 7.

```
Fatal error compiling: error: release version 11 not supported
```

I was having jre but missing jdk. You can figure this out by running `javac` command. It is says command not found then there is need to install jdk.

To install Java 11 JDK

```
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

To install Java 11 JRE

```
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk
```

More details here. I found this useful.

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-java-on-centos

Answer (score 5):

For me, this came from having a Java 11 JRE installed and not a JDK.  The folder name had "jdk" in it, so I assumed it was correct, but looking in the `/bin` folder I didn't see a `javac` executable, so I think it was falling back to the default Java on the system which was earlier than Java 11.

Comment: Same thing, "javac" command was not working so I realized that it is JRE, not JDK

Answer (score 5):

I see you are using Java 9, to be build with Java 11, please try the below:

1. Ensure JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11......
2. In your pom.xml add `"<properties> <java.version>11</java.version> </properties>"` and reference ${java.version} where applicable.
3. "mvn -v" should output something like this (depending where your maven and java installations sit in your machine):
   Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T21:00:29+02:00)
   Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache-Maven-3.6.1\bin..
   Java version: 11.0.6, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6
   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
   OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
4. Then retry mvn clean install
5. If no luck, please share your pom.xml so that we can see the configuration that may be throwing your build off.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:

mvn -version

Examples - Java version: 9.0.4

Further used plugin:

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<configuration>
<release>9.0.4</release>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when using the Docker image [`adoptopenjdk/openjdk13:alpine-slim`](https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk13): [The JDK "slim" image does not support the "--release" flag in the javac command](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/issues/103)

Answer (score 0):

For me a deceivingly similar error, specifically `java.lang.AssertionError`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project nospringboot: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.AssertionError: Version '14' not supported -> [Help 1]
```

occurred because of one of the dependencies. I've replaced

```
<groupId>org.testifyproject.mock</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito</artifactId>
<version>1.0.6</version>
```

with

```
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
<version>1.9.5</version>
```

and it's working. I realised this when I ran maven build in [verbose mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898801/how-do-i-get-verbose-output-from-maven-in-the-eclipse-console/16899799#16899799) and it printed this output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Version '14' not supported
    at org.testifyproject.processor.DiscoverableProcessor.getSupportedSourceVersion(DiscoverableProcessor.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.checkSourceVersionCompatibility(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:764)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:704)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:830)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:926)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1270)
...
```

which shows which method (in which **specific package**: `org.testifyproject.processor.DiscoverableProcessor.getSupportedSourceVersion(DiscoverableProcessor.java:67`) produced the negative assertion.

Answer (score 0):

as the message specify, this is a version problem, i bootstrap a spring project and i selected java 11 when i actually had java 8 on my pc. i simply went bach to re-create my project with the approriate java veersion and the error went away

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error in Eclipse, try compiling your project outside Eclipse after downloading and setting up the latest Maven version (including setting up `MAVEN_HOME` environement variable to your installation path).

If your project compiles outside Eclipse but not inside, then check the jdk used by your Maven configuration :

- In Eclipse : Run | Run Configurations...
- Select your `Maven Build` configuration
- Select the `JRE` tab and make sure the right JRE is used.
- Repeat for your other Maven configurations

Answer (score 0):

Having this in your pom:

```
  <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

And a different java version set, java 8 in my case, can cuase the issue:

```
 za$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8+7 (build 17.0.8+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.8+7 (build 17.0.8+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Need to be consistent.